# Groovy Code- Matching a field using regex and generating blank value if not a match

Tags: java, groovy

I have a field that was created based on some parsed and reformatted data. If the final result does not match a specific pattern, I want to replace it with just a blank value. I have some groovy code written but I continue to get errors of "No such property" when I run it.

I have tried poking around online and moving the code around but with my very limited experience I am not having any luck.

```
def formattedData=data['FormattedNum']
def regExpStr=[A-Z]{5}[':'][0-9]{4}

if (formattedData.matches(regExpStr)){
    formattedData
} else {
    formattedData =''
}  ;
```

My expected results would be to retain the data['FormattedNum'] if it matches the regex and if it doesn't, just replace whatever is in that field as a blank.

Answer (score 0):

What is data? Is it a map?
Lets assume it is and it's out of scope in the method or wherever this code is located...

```
def data = [FormattedNum: 'ABCDE:0123']
def formattedData= data['FormattedNum']
def regExpStr = /[A-Z]{5}[':'][0-9]{4}/
if (formattedData.matches(regExpStr)){     
    formattedData 
} 
else { 
    formattedData = '' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def formattedData = data['FormattedNum']
if (!(formattedData ==~ '[A-Z]{5}:[0-9]{4}')) {
   formattedData = ''
}
```

`==~` matches the subject with the regular expression as explained [in the official Groovy doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_match_operator). It has the same semantics as calling `matches` on a string but in groovy way